# Navigation on touch-enabled devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, user-interface, mobile

Now that we don't have to just worry about dealing with touch events on mobile devices, but also the fact that basically every new Windows 10 Laptop sold today is a touch screen, what are the best practices for touch friendly navigation on websites? Sub-Menus, specifically, have always been a pain on touch devices. I've used different jQuery snippets with varying levels of success. Is there an accepted/canonical way (maybe something in jQuery UI?) of dealing with this issue yet?

Comment: Something like: https://github.com/mango/slideout , https://github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation and https://github.com/viljamis/responsive-nav.js ?

Comment: Yeah, I mean those are all nice, advanced third-party options. But I was wondering if there was an officially accepted 'basic' way of doing it

Comment: Not sure, everything is changing... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events is a good start, also these are interesting: http://www.zdnet.com/article/google-is-back-on-board-with-pointer-events-but-what-about-apple/ - http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/
Too much :D

Answer (score 0):

As just a basic way of doing it I would like to recommend using something like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zwr43zjb/), simpler then this would be hard. This is the way I always use and I would say its just a matter of opinion on whats best to use :)

```
$('#menuToggle').bind("click", function() {
    $('#menu').toggle();
})
```